# [FORMBODY parameters null?

Tags: mysql, json, utf-8, asp.net-web-api

I created the Insert method to insert the data in Mysql using entity when testing with fiddler

I solution of this url but not wroking to me
[Fiddler testing API Post passing a [Frombody] class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395669/fiddler-testing-api-post-passing-a-frombody-class)

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:4086
Content-Length: 193
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Above format showing null for collection object

```
public class InsertController : BaseApiController
{
    static readonly IInsertMaster obj = new InsertMaster();

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostUser(collection_master collection)
    {
        if (collection == null)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "not created");

        if (obj.PostUser(collection))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, TheModelFactory.create(collection));
        }
        else
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not save to the database");
    }

}
```

Input:

```
 {"CustomerID":"10","AmountRecevied":1000","Date_Time":"2014-03-03 10:00:00","Area":"banglore","AgentID":"1","Money_Receipt_No":"123456","Payment_Mode":"cheque","Money_Receipt_Photo":null}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
   Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

or

JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode. The default encoding is UTF-8.

Since the first two characters of a JSON text will always be ASCII characters [RFC0020], it is possible to determine whether an octet stream is UTF-8, UTF-16 (BE or LE), or UTF-32 (BE or LE) by looking at the pattern of nulls in the first four octets.
      00 00 00 xx  UTF-32BE
      00 xx 00 xx  UTF-16BE
      xx 00 00 00  UTF-32LE
      xx 00 xx 00  UTF-16LE
      xx xx xx xx  UTF-8

Check  Here
[What does "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean)